# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n+1}$ almost everywhere

Tags: uniform-convergence, almost-everywhere

I am trying to show that $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n+1}&0\leq x\leq e^n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad$$ converges almost everywhere, in measure space $  (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B(R)}, \mu)$. Any comments will be a great help. 
Thank you.

I tried considering $\epsilon > 0$, and a positive integer $N$ such that $1/e^n <\epsilon $, but how can I proceed from here. How to conclude it converges almost everywhere.
please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean: $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n+1}&0\leq x\leq e^n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad$?

Comment: @Thomas, Yes, That is the function.

Comment: Try $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Lan, Could u please explain in detail if possible. I am trying to understand the concept clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no almost everywhere needed in this question. For any $n,x$, $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$, so if $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq \epsilon$.